# Android application is not working properly in mobile but working in emulator

Tags: java, android

I want to design a login page in android accessing a MySQL database using PHP,

Application is working fine on emulator but not on mobile it is not even entering in backgroung.java second time I click the button I think as it is not printing entered message in logcat any help will be appreciated as I am new in android.

**Main Activity**

```
public void clicklogin(View view) {
    //validate(email.getText().toString(),pass.getText().toString());
    String username = email.getText().toString();
    String password = pass.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";
    BackgroungWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroungWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
    Log.i("check msg","clicked");


}
```

**BackgroungWorker**

```
public class BackgroungWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

BackgroungWorker(Context ctx)
{
    context=ctx;
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    Log.i("check msg","entered");
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://192.168.0.110/login.php";

    if(type.equals("login")) {
        try {
            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            Log.i("check msg","hello "+result);
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result+"hi");
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```

}

```
2020-04-06 02:49:49.622 24596-24620/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-04-06 02:49:49.622 24596-24620/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2020-04-06 02:49:49.635 24596-24596/? I/ViewConfigCompat: Could not find method getScaledScrollFactor() on ViewConfiguration
2020-04-06 02:49:49.699 24596-24608/? D/ActivityThread: scheduleCPUPowerControlForApp pkgName:com.example.myapplication using hwrender:true
2020-04-06 02:49:57.404 24596-24596/com.example.myapplication I/check msg: clicked
2020-04-06 02:49:57.405 24596-24638/com.example.myapplication I/check msg: entered
2020-04-06 02:49:57.407 24596-24638/com.example.myapplication D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-04-06 02:50:01.667 24596-24596/com.example.myapplication I/check msg: clicked
2020-04-06 02:50:02.882 24596-24596/com.example.myapplication I/check msg: clicked
2020-04-06 02:50:09.626 24596-24596/com.example.myapplication I/check msg: clicked
2020-04-06 02:50:09.838 24596-24596/com.example.myapplication I/check msg: clicked
2020-04-06 02:50:10.253 24596-24596/com.example.myapplication I/check msg: clicked
```

Comment: It's probably failing to connect and timing out, and it's not entering the doInBackground because the first one hasn't finished yet.   You should consider using a different method for background work than AsyncTasks on a serial executor, in large part because of issues like this.

Comment: I think its problem of the api. Check minsdk of your app. Probably minsdk is bigger than your phone's api.

Comment: @RyanM can you tell what method should I use instead of AsyncTasks I am new at android or any link that can give a hint, Thanks.

Comment: I tried to go on google chrome on my mobile device and to test server I entered 192.168.0.110 but was not able to access swamp server I think the problem is there.

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin if the minSdkVersion were greater than the phone's API level, the app would be unable to install.  That's clearly not the case here.

Comment: @k180963MohsinAli Sure!  It actually depends a bit on what your needs are.  Here's an article that can help you decide: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads

Comment: I posted answer which worked for me but someone deleted I don't know why ?

Comment: Thanks all for your help specially @Ryan M